# Restricted elliptic curves in Java Card

Tags: java, cryptography, javacard, elliptic-curve

I am trying to implement cryptographic algorithms on elliptic curve in Java Card.

First, I implemented it on 256bits elliptic curve (the NIST one) and it worked well.

Now I want to test it on a 512bits curve (and not 521 like the NIST one). My card support this size and I found a database of elliptic curves (well defined for cryptography) of this size.
But I am encountering a strange problem...

When I try to initialize my key:

```
ECPublicKey pubKey = (ECPublicKey) KeyBuilder.buildKey(
            KeyBuilder.TYPE_EC_FP_PUBLIC, (short) 0x0200, false);

pubKey.setFieldFP(new byte[] { (byte) 0x25, (byte) 0x37,
            (byte) 0xD2, (byte) 0x9C, (byte) 0x8B, (byte) 0xFE,
            (byte) 0x7D, (byte) 0x9F, (byte) 0x48, (byte) 0x98,
            (byte) 0xF7, (byte) 0x60, (byte) 0xF8, (byte) 0x7D,
            (byte) 0xBF, (byte) 0x63, (byte) 0x90, (byte) 0x6E,
            (byte) 0x28, (byte) 0x99, (byte) 0x0A, (byte) 0x27,
            (byte) 0x0C, (byte) 0xA6, (byte) 0x15, (byte) 0xD9,
            (byte) 0x1D, (byte) 0xC4, (byte) 0x89, (byte) 0xA8,
            (byte) 0xD0, (byte) 0xA1, (byte) 0xA0, (byte) 0xE7,
            (byte) 0x52, (byte) 0x43, (byte) 0xB0, (byte) 0x39,
            (byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x6A, (byte) 0x61, (byte) 0x43,
            (byte) 0x5C, (byte) 0xA5, (byte) 0x91, (byte) 0xE9,
            (byte) 0x4B, (byte) 0x1A, (byte) 0xF7, (byte) 0x60,
            (byte) 0xC9, (byte) 0xAE, (byte) 0xE2, (byte) 0xCE,
            (byte) 0xE0, (byte) 0x15, (byte) 0x53, (byte) 0x51,
            (byte) 0x1C, (byte) 0x93, (byte) 0x0E, (byte) 0xF3,
            (byte) 0xBA, (byte) 0x0B }, (short) 0x0000, (short) 0x0040);
```

The function `setFieldFP` raises a `CryptoException` with the reason code `ILLEGAL_VALUE` which means that the key length doesn't match... But it does (`0x0200` is the size of the curve in bits and `0X0040` is the length of the prime in bytes)!

I said it is really strange because if I try with the following value:

```
ECPublicKey pubKey = (ECPublicKey) KeyBuilder.buildKey(
            KeyBuilder.TYPE_EC_FP_PUBLIC, (short) 0x0200, false);

pubKey.setFieldFP(new byte[] { (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xFF,
            (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00,
            (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00,
            (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00,
            (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00,
            (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xFF,
            (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xFF,
            (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xFF,
            (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xFF,
            (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00,
            (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00,
            (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00,
            (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00,
            (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xFF,
            (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xFF,
            (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xFF,
            (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xFF}, (short) 0x0000, (short) 0x0040);
```

It works fine...

So I have to conclude that the `CryptoException` that is raised doesn't really concern the size of the parameter because, in the two cases, the size is the same...

So what? Does my card only support elliptic curve on specific fields? Has someone ever encountered this kind of problem?

Comment: Where did you find your values?

Comment: The value that I want to use is issued from the project `Arcana-ECDB` (free data base of elliptic curves for cryptography). I tested some things in Java and it works fine.
The second one that doesn't raise the `CryptoException` is just the prime `p` defined in the  P-256 curve from the NIST that I wrote two times to have a 64 bytes array...

Comment: Are you sure your value is big-endian and right-aligned?

Comment: Yes I am, in decimal it is `p=1949267833991132156624567702038114900258750954300540297313343803851286200632152793789301494716697433175386117075231418405857650629212030482306845113563659` which is `25 37 D2 9C 8B FE 7D 9F 48 98 F7 60 F8 7D BF 63 90 6E 28 99 0A 27 0C A6 15 D9 1D C4 89 A8 D0 A1 A0 E7 52 43 B0 39 01 6A 61 43 5C A5 91 E9 4B 1A F7 60 C9 AE E2 CE E0 15 53 51 1C 93 0E F3 BA 0B` in hexadecimal

Comment: What kind of card? Note that there are differences in supported and supported after initialization. The fact that the chip supports 512 bit ECC also doesn't mean that the platform does.

Comment: My card is a Cosmo V7 from Oberthur Card System. I understand what you mention but I am able to do ECC with NIST's P-521 elliptic curve so that is really confusing...

Comment: As I see above, the only difference between two above case is the value of `FieldFP`! Just the value is different and even the size is equal?! Really?!

Comment: @Abraham Thanks for the hint :) Answered it.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Your welcome. Actually, When I leave the above comment, I didn't know that my question can transfer to a hint in future ;) You have really lynx-eyed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your prime is not big enough. For curves over F(p) of 512 bit you should use 512 bit primes. Your first byte, `(byte) 0x25`, however starts with a hex digit `2`. That means that the first byte first starts with 2 binary digits set to `0`, meaning that you've defined a 512 - 2 = 510 bit prime.

Please use only well defined curves, such as the NIST P521 curve or the BrainpoolP512r1 curve.

Comment: Wow! Hard-to-debug error! So we must consider that the high nibble of first byte must be greater than `8` always?

Comment: Well, yes, unless the card supports 510 bit curves as well. But I wonder how the prime was generated (it *is* a prime, I checked).

Comment: May I know why you wondering about the prime number generation? Is it hard to generate a 512 bit prime number on _nowadays_ Java Cards?(because of card's resource restrictions, for example). Anyway, based on the first questioner's comment under his post, I think the prime number is generated off-card.

Comment: Well, no, generating a 512 bit prime is half as hard as generating a 1024 bit key pair. Not hard, but it will take time. Generating domain parameters - including the prime - should however not be attempted outside a controlled environment, and certainly not on a smart card. It seems that the prime generation is - for instance - restricted to `[1..  2^512)` instead of `[2^511 ... 2^512)`.

Comment: Wow, indeed it was hard to debugg, thank you very much! If you want to know more about the construction of these elliptic curves, you can download the project `Arcana-ECDB` on the website `AcryptA`. It contains a paper that explains how they proceed to build this database : http://www.acrypta.com/telechargements/ell_tech_report_public.pdf
Thank you again :)