# brainpool320r1 Elliptic Curve not supported in Java Card?

Tags: java, cryptography, smartcard, javacard, elliptic-curve

I am working on a Java Card 3.0.1 applet on which I use ECC.
My card supports ECC GF(p) up to 320bits, so I tried to use the `brainpool320r1` elliptic curve ([parameters](http://www.ecc-brainpool.org/download/Domain-parameters.pdf)). The problem is that I get a `CryptoException` that I don't understand... It is the same kind of problem that I had a few time ago: [Restricted elliptic curves in Java Card](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31185206/restricted-elliptic-curves-in-java-card) but the solution given doesn't match with this case (the curve is well defined with a 320bits prime).

I post the corresponding code :

```
byte[] p = new byte[] { (byte) 0xD3, (byte) 0x5E, (byte) 0x47, (byte) 0x20,
        (byte) 0x36, (byte) 0xBC, (byte) 0x4F, (byte) 0xB7,
        (byte) 0xE1, (byte) 0x3C, (byte) 0x78, (byte) 0x5E,
        (byte) 0xD2, (byte) 0x01, (byte) 0xE0, (byte) 0x65,
        (byte) 0xF9, (byte) 0x8F, (byte) 0xCF, (byte) 0xA6,
        (byte) 0xF6, (byte) 0xF4, (byte) 0x0D, (byte) 0xEF,
        (byte) 0x4F, (byte) 0x92, (byte) 0xB9, (byte) 0xEC,
        (byte) 0x78, (byte) 0x93, (byte) 0xEC, (byte) 0x28,
        (byte) 0xFC, (byte) 0xD4, (byte) 0x12, (byte) 0xB1,
        (byte) 0xF1, (byte) 0xB3, (byte) 0x2E, (byte) 0x27 };

byte[] a = new byte[] { (byte) 0x3E, (byte) 0xE3, (byte) 0x0B, (byte) 0x56,
    (byte) 0x8F, (byte) 0xBA, (byte) 0xB0, (byte) 0xF8,
    (byte) 0x83, (byte) 0xCC, (byte) 0xEB, (byte) 0xD4,
    (byte) 0x6D, (byte) 0x3F, (byte) 0x3B, (byte) 0xB8,
    (byte) 0xA2, (byte) 0xA7, (byte) 0x35, (byte) 0x13,
    (byte) 0xF5, (byte) 0xEB, (byte) 0x79, (byte) 0xDA,
    (byte) 0x66, (byte) 0x19, (byte) 0x0E, (byte) 0xB0,
    (byte) 0x85, (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xA9, (byte) 0xF4,
    (byte) 0x92, (byte) 0xF3, (byte) 0x75, (byte) 0xA9,
    (byte) 0x7D, (byte) 0x86, (byte) 0x0E, (byte) 0xB4 };

byte[] b = new byte[] { (byte) 0x52, (byte) 0x08, (byte) 0x83, (byte) 0x94,
    (byte) 0x9D, (byte) 0xFD, (byte) 0xBC, (byte) 0x42,
    (byte) 0xD3, (byte) 0xAD, (byte) 0x19, (byte) 0x86,
    (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x68, (byte) 0x8A, (byte) 0x6F,
    (byte) 0xE1, (byte) 0x3F, (byte) 0x41, (byte) 0x34,
    (byte) 0x95, (byte) 0x54, (byte) 0xB4, (byte) 0x9A,
    (byte) 0xCC, (byte) 0x31, (byte) 0xDC, (byte) 0xCD,
    (byte) 0x88, (byte) 0x45, (byte) 0x39, (byte) 0x81,
    (byte) 0x6F, (byte) 0x5E, (byte) 0xB4, (byte) 0xAC,
    (byte) 0x8F, (byte) 0xB1, (byte) 0xF1, (byte) 0xA6 };

byte[] r = new byte[] { (byte) 0xD3, (byte) 0x5E, (byte) 0x47, (byte) 0x20,
    (byte) 0x36, (byte) 0xBC, (byte) 0x4F, (byte) 0xB7,
    (byte) 0xE1, (byte) 0x3C, (byte) 0x78, (byte) 0x5E,
    (byte) 0xD2, (byte) 0x01, (byte) 0xE0, (byte) 0x65,
    (byte) 0xF9, (byte) 0x8F, (byte) 0xCF, (byte) 0xA5,
    (byte) 0xB6, (byte) 0x8F, (byte) 0x12, (byte) 0xA3,
    (byte) 0x2D, (byte) 0x48, (byte) 0x2E, (byte) 0xC7,
    (byte) 0xEE, (byte) 0x86, (byte) 0x58, (byte) 0xE9,
    (byte) 0x86, (byte) 0x91, (byte) 0x55, (byte) 0x5B,
    (byte) 0x44, (byte) 0xC5, (byte) 0x93, (byte) 0x11 };

byte[] g = new byte[] { (byte) 0x04, (byte) 0x43, (byte) 0xBD, (byte) 0x7E,
    (byte) 0x9A, (byte) 0xFB, (byte) 0x53, (byte) 0xD8,
    (byte) 0xB8, (byte) 0x52, (byte) 0x89, (byte) 0xBC,
    (byte) 0xC4, (byte) 0x8E, (byte) 0xE5, (byte) 0xBF,
    (byte) 0xE6, (byte) 0xF2, (byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x37,
    (byte) 0xD1, (byte) 0x0A, (byte) 0x08, (byte) 0x7E,
    (byte) 0xB6, (byte) 0xE7, (byte) 0x87, (byte) 0x1E,
    (byte) 0x2A, (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0xA5, (byte) 0x99,
    (byte) 0xC7, (byte) 0x10, (byte) 0xAF, (byte) 0x8D,
    (byte) 0x0D, (byte) 0x39, (byte) 0xE2, (byte) 0x06,
    (byte) 0x11, (byte) 0x14, (byte) 0xFD, (byte) 0xD0,
    (byte) 0x55, (byte) 0x45, (byte) 0xEC, (byte) 0x1C,
    (byte) 0xC8, (byte) 0xAB, (byte) 0x40, (byte) 0x93,
    (byte) 0x24, (byte) 0x7F, (byte) 0x77, (byte) 0x27,
    (byte) 0x5E, (byte) 0x07, (byte) 0x43, (byte) 0xFF,
    (byte) 0xED, (byte) 0x11, (byte) 0x71, (byte) 0x82,
    (byte) 0xEA, (byte) 0xA9, (byte) 0xC7, (byte) 0x78,
    (byte) 0x77, (byte) 0xAA, (byte) 0xAC, (byte) 0x6A,
    (byte) 0xC7, (byte) 0xD3, (byte) 0x52, (byte) 0x45,
    (byte) 0xD1, (byte) 0x69, (byte) 0x2E, (byte) 0x8E, (byte) 0xE1 };

    ECPublicKey ecdhPubKey = (ECPublicKey) KeyBuilder.buildKey(
            KeyBuilder.TYPE_EC_FP_PUBLIC, (short) 0x0140, false);
    ecdhPubKey.setFieldFP(p, (short) 0x0000, (short) 0x0028);
    ecdhPubKey.setA(a, (short) 0x0000, (short) 0x0028);
    ecdhPubKey.setB(b, (short) 0x0000, (short) 0x0028);
    ecdhPubKey.setR(r, (short) 0x0000, (short) 0x0028);
    ecdhPubKey.setG(g, (short) 0x0000, (short) g.length);

    ECPrivateKey ecdhPrivKey = (ECPrivateKey) KeyBuilder.buildKey(
        KeyBuilder.TYPE_EC_FP_PRIVATE, (short) 0x0140, false);

    // Generate a key pair (x, xG) for ECDH.
    KeyPair keypair = new KeyPair(ecdhPubKey, ecdhPrivKey);
    keypair.genKeyPair();
```

I checked step by step, all is going right, except the last line `keypair.genKeyPair();` that raises a `CryptoException.ILLEGAL_VALUE`. In the Java Card specifications, it is said it means that the values `FP`, `A`, `B`, `R` and `G` specified for the `ECPublicKey` are invalid... I verified, it corresponds well to the `brainpool520r1`. So what ? Am I doing something wrong ? Is this curve not well defined for ECC ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Well, the same code with 256 bit curve (brainpool and NIST) give the same result... So what to conclude? That the Java Card runtime configuration doesn't support ECC? How can I check it? The smart card specifications say that ECC Gf(p) 320 bit is supported.

Comment: It's probably that you don't set K to be the value one (using `ECKey.setK`). If that doesn't work copy the domain parameters to the private key as well.

Comment: Indeed, after setting the domain parameters for the private key, it works. Thank you so much. But the Java Card specification mentioned that only the public key has to "know" the domain parameters right? I already developped applet without needing to do it for private key so what? Depend from vendors? Thank you again anyway :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [Maarten Bodewes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/589259/maarten-bodewes) said in comments above, **the problem is that I didn't set the domain parameters** for the `ECPrivateKey` although Java Card specifications mentions that it is only necessary for `ECPublicKey`.

Comment: Yep, that may be a small mistake from the card vendor. Note that during EC key generation the private key is generated first, so it's not that strange if the implementation forgets to copy the parameters in advance. What platform are you using?

Comment: OK, thanks for the precision :) The platform used is `JCOP v2.4.2`.